# Convert list entries to array

Tags: c#, arrays, list

In order to generate a graph using d3 I need to convert my list of time entries to several arrays.

I store my data in a list of work records per day per staff

I need to be able to get an array of all days, and then a array each per member of staff.

So lets say staff x has 3.5h against 01/1/19 and 4.5h against 03/1/19
Staff y has 6h agaist 2/1/19

I'd expect my arrays to look as following:

```
Dates[1/1/19, 2/1/19, 3/1/19]
X[3.5,0,4.5]
Y[0,6,0]
```

Some of my code is:

```
public IEnumerable<TicketWorkRecord> TimeByDateByStaff { get; set; }

public class TicketWorkRecord
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal TimeSpent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is time to add ALL your code attempts?

Answer (score 0):

If `TicketWorkRecord` has a property specifying which staff member it is (X or Y), then this would be pretty straight forward using LINQ:

```
var dates = TimeByDateByStaff.Select(x => x.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yy")).ToArray();
var staffXTimeSpent = TimeByDateByStaff.Select(x => x.StaffMember == "X" ? x.TimeSpent : 0M).ToArray();
var staffYTimeSpent = TimeByDateByStaff.Select(x => x.StaffMember == "Y" ? x.TimeSpent : 0M).ToArray();
```

Alternatively, if the exact staff members aren't known at compile time then you can get the time entries by staff member at runtime:

```
var timeSpentByStaffMembers = TimeByDateByStaff
    .Select(x => x.StaffMember)
    .Distinct()
    .ToDictionary(
        key => key, 
        value => TimeByDateByStaff.Select(x => x.StaffMember == value ? x.TimeSpent : 0M).ToArray());
```

---

With the following data:

```
var TimeByDateByStaff = new List<TicketWorkRecord>
{
    new TicketWorkRecord
    {
        Date = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1),
        TimeSpent = 3.5M,
        StaffMember = "X"
    },
    new TicketWorkRecord
    {
        Date = new DateTime(2019, 2, 1),
        TimeSpent = 6M,
        StaffMember = "Y"
    },
    new TicketWorkRecord
    {
        Date = new DateTime(2019, 3, 1),
        TimeSpent = 4.5M,
        StaffMember = "X"
    }
};
```

The LINQ statements above produce the following output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you want to split your list of objects into individuals fields arrays.

If yes, Lets say you have the following list

```
List<Object> ObjectsList = ObjectsList;
string[] ExtractDates = ObjectsList.Select(x=>x.Date).ToArray();
double[] TimeSpent = ObjectsList.Select(x=> x.TimeSpent).ToArray();
```

and so forth, you can apply where condition to filter based on members

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a class called `StaffMember` that looks like this:

```
public class StaffMember
{
    public IEnumerable<TicketWorkRecord> TimeByDateByStaff { get; set; }
    // Other properties
}
```

And after adding the following constructor to your `TicketWorkRecord` class:

```
public TicketWorkRecord(DateTime date, decimal timeSpent)
{
    Date = date;
    TimeSpent = timeSpent;
}
```

Let's create a dummy data for `X` and `Y` staff members:

```
StaffMember X = new StaffMember
{
    TimeByDateByStaff = new List<TicketWorkRecord>()
                        {
                            new TicketWorkRecord(DateTime.Today.Date, 3.5M),
                            new TicketWorkRecord(DateTime.Today.Date.AddDays(2), 4.5M)
                        }
};
StaffMember Y = new StaffMember
{
    TimeByDateByStaff = new List<TicketWorkRecord>()
                        { new TicketWorkRecord(DateTime.Today.Date.AddDays(1), 6M) }
};

var staffMembers = new List<StaffMember>() { X, Y };
```

Now, you can construct your desired 3 arrays using the following code:

```
var dates = staffMembers.SelectMany(s => s.TimeByDateByStaff)
                                        .Select(t => t.Date)
                                        .Distinct()
                                        .OrderBy(d => d).ToArray();
var xTimes = dates.Select(d => X.TimeByDateByStaff
                                .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Date == d)?.TimeSpent ?? 0).ToArray();
var yTimes = dates.Select(d => Y.TimeByDateByStaff
                                .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Date == d)?.TimeSpent ?? 0).ToArray();
```

---

**To test it:**

```
Console.WriteLine("Dates: " + string.Join(",", dates.Select(d => d.ToShortDateString())));
Console.WriteLine("xTimes: " + string.Join(",", xTimes));
Console.WriteLine("yTimes: " + string.Join(",", yTimes));
```

**Output:**

```
Dates: 12/01/2019,13/01/2019,14/01/2019
xTimes: 3.5,0,4.5
yTimes: 0,6,0
```